# Determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix where $n$ is unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, determinant, matrix-equations

I´m trying to solve the following problem:

Let $a$ be a scalar. Consider the set $\left\{ v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n} \right\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that the $i$th element of $v_{i}$ is equal to 1 and the rest of the elements are equal to $a$ ($i=1,2,...,n)$. The scalar $a$ needs to meet 2 conditions for the set $\left\{ v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n} \right\}$ to be linearly independent. ¿Which are these 2 conditions?

This is a translation I made of the original problem which is in spanish. I think there is a possibility that I´m not translating it well so I´m attaching a picture of the problem at the end of this post if anyone that speaks spanish sees this post can tell me if I´m making a correct translation (I don´t know if this is against the rules so sorry if I break one).

Either way, what I understand is this:$$v_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
a\\
a\\
...\\
a
\end{pmatrix}, v_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
1\\
a\\
...\\
a
\end{pmatrix},...,v_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
a\\
a\\
...\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

So, for the set to be linearly independent:
$$M_{n \times n}\overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{0}\to \overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{0}$$
If the determinant of $M$ is $0$, then the system of equations has no unique solution (infinite or none) and therefore the set wouldn´t be L.I. so $|M|\neq0$ . The thing is that I don´t know how to compute the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix. I founded the determinant of the following matrices:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 &a  &a  \\
a &1  &a  \\
a &a  &1 
\end{vmatrix} ,  \begin{vmatrix}
1 &a  &a  &a  \\
a &1  &a  &a  \\
a &a  &1  &a  \\
a &a  &a  &1 
\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}
1 &  a&a  &a  &a  \\
 a&  1&  a& a &  a\\
 a&a  &1  & a & a \\
 a& a &  a&1  &a  \\
 a&  a&  a&  a&1 
\end{vmatrix}$$ and the answers were $(1-a)^{2}(2a+1),(1-a)^{3}(3a+1)$ and $(1-a)^{4}(4a+1)$ respectively. Supposing that  $|M|=(1-a)^{n-1}((n-1)a+1)$, by algebraic manipulation, I got that $a\neq1$ and $a\neq1/(1-n)$.

The thing is that i don´t think i can´t just assume that $|M|=(1-a)^{n-1}((n-1)a+1)$ based on "smaller versions" of $M$, or can I? If not, how do I prove it? by induction? Also, are this really the 2 conditions the problem is asking for?

Original problem in spanish:
[image: Original problem in spanish]

Comment: I guess using induction is ok.

Comment: @AngaeMT Can you explain how to do it? This course is "introductory" to linear algebra so i don´t know how do it. In some previous math course they taught us how to calculate determinants for cramer´s rule but nothing more.

Also, how much time and paper would it take? This problem is from a past 1-hour-and-40-minute long practice exam which doesn´t has unlimited paper to answer. So is there another way to prove it besides induction?

Comment: Since this question is duplicated, I suggest you going to the duplicated question to check for the solution (which I think the chosen method is quite smart).